# unexpected keyword argument within init

Tags: python, networkx, init

I try tu run a model with python (no built by me) and I obtain this error:

[image]

This comes from:

```
from seirsplus.models import *
import networkx

numNodes = 10000
baseGraph    = networkx.barabasi_albert_graph(n=numNodes, m=9)
G_normal     = custom_exponential_graph(baseGraph, scale=100)
# Social distancing interactions:
G_distancing = custom_exponential_graph(baseGraph, scale=10)
# Quarantine interactions:
G_quarantine = custom_exponential_graph(baseGraph, scale=5)

model = SEIRSNetworkModel(G=G_normal, beta=0.155, sigma=1/5.2, gamma=1/12.39, mu_I=0.0004, p=0.5,
                          Q=G_quarantine, beta_D=0.155, sigma_D=1/5.2, gamma_D=1/12.39, mu_D=0.0004,
                          theta_E=0.02, theta_I=0.02, phi_E=0.2, phi_I=0.2, psi_E=1.0, psi_I=1.0, q=0.5,
                          initI=10)

checkpoints = {'t': [20, 100], 'G': [G_distancing, G_normal], 'p': [0.1, 0.5], 'theta_E': [0.02, 0.02], 'theta_I': [0.02, 0.02], 'phi_E':   [0.2, 0.2], 'phi_I':   [0.2, 0.2]}

model.run(T=300, checkpoints=checkpoints)

model.figure_infections()
```

i leave it with an image to see the highlighted part.

From what I understand, this has to do with the way the class SEIRSNetworkModel is constructed. I already forked the original repository:

https://github.com/ryansmcgee/seirsplus/wiki/SEIRSNetworkModel-class

but I don´t know where to look for this constructor, and what to search for in order to fix this problem. This may be too simple, but I can´t find my way.

I'd appreciate any help, as simple as possible please since you can see I don't know how to navigate in here.

Comment: So, the `SEIRSNetworkModel` object's constructor does not have the `Q` argument that you expect it to have. Did you fork from an older version of its repo, before `Q` was added? What makes you think it should have `Q`? Are you using a tutorial that might be out of date?

Comment: I figured that (that Q argument is needed but nof found), but like I said, I checked into repository, and cant find the constructor to check it (it sure there exists, but I dont know how to get there). 
The version is the latest, or at least there hasnt been changes in the last years.
In the documentation Q is mentioned as one of the parameters the funcion needs, that is why i believe it to be needed.

Comment: That page has no constructor argument called `Q`. The closest one I could find is just plain `q`. Of course since Python names are case-sensitive, these are completely distinct. There's `G_Q` which has an uppercase `Q` but I assume that's not the one you want, and that you probably you just want plain lowercase `q`.

Comment: Thanks. In its documentation page, creator talks about that argument ¿did you got the chance to see the code for constructor? Or just guessed from instructions on parameters?

Comment: I looked at the page you linked, and read through the "required" and "additional" parameters' "constructor argument" column. That's all I did. The source code can be easily found - [here](https://github.com/ryansmcgee/seirsplus/blob/6fe794dc5525eee33fa7cabee16d282bf4b02eba/seirsplus/models.py#L524) it is. If you look through it, again, you'll see that there's no `Q` argument. Just `q`. You said "its documentation page, creator talks about that argument" but I don't see where, you have to be more specific if you want me to see what you mean.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue - the author's example on the readme, [here](https://github.com/ryansmcgee/seirsplus#code-usage), contains the `Q` argument. So, it looks like the example they have is just wrong. So, your mistake was copying and pasting the code without understanding it, but that would've been fine, except that the code also had a mistake so there was no way for you to catch it because it was copied and pasted.

Comment: I reported the issue here so the author can fix their README.MD: https://github.com/ryansmcgee/seirsplus/issues/62

Comment: Thank you so much. For a moment I thought that that would may be an error, but I wasnt sure, so that is why I asked for help, but you have found it. So I guess I better run it without invoking Q.

Comment: Yeah I think all you have to do is change `Q` to `q` but I'm no expert on what you're actually trying to accomplish. I just have general Python experience. I don't think you should omit the argument because that might have unintended consequences.

Comment: Neither am I, im using for first time this. I wan to understand and use the model, but I need to know how it works. The documentation says it has some default values for arguments, but if I run it like it is, well, that's where I started. 

The system is saying no extended discussions in comments. So to me either i put some random value to see where it leads, change Q to q, or I dont know what else. Thank you so much again.